# Sending JSON data to rest api

Tags: api, rest

I have started to learn about REST API. So far I have been able to call my REST API post data using the form and also to get values from my REST API. Now I am trying to learn to send my data to my REST API using JSON object. I have been searching on the net and reading on StackOverflow on how to implement it but so far there is no luck. I am looking for some basic code examples where I can get an idea of how it's done. If some could help me with some codes on how to send data to my REST API using JSON and also how to retrieve that JSON data in my REST API it will be very helpful to me in learning REST API(Just the basic codes I hope it shouldn't take much of your time to post some codes). Btw I am using Jersey to implement my REST API. Thanks in Advance :) It really will be helpful to me in understanding sending JSON data to my web service Thanks again :)
The language is JAVA(JAX-RS implemented in Jersey)

Comment: At least mention the language/platform you are using...

Comment: JAX-RS implemented in Jersey

Answer (score 0, accepted):

While sending data in json request, your request should be in the form of a map (key value pair ). Key should be your attribute name and values as the value for the attribute.

For example if you are trying to find a employee using employeeid the your request should be of the form **{data:{"employeeid":"1"}}**

Be more specif about which platform you are using to call the RESTservice.

Hope this will help you.

Answer (score 0):

```
var clientCreateOrder = new RestClient("#######################");
                var requestCreateOrder = new RestRequest(Method.POST);
                request.AddHeader("Content-Type", "application/json");
//Use below code for creating and sending dynamic json objects to RESTAPI
                object[] purchase_units_arr = new object[1];
                purchase_units_arr[0] = new
                {
                    amount = new
                    {
                        currency_code = "USD",
                        value = "100.00"
                    }
                };

                var body = new
                {
                    intent = "CAPTURE",
                    purchase_units = purchase_units_arr,
                };
//Serialize Json object
                request.AddParameter("undefined", new JavaScriptSerializer().Serialize(body).ToString(), ParameterType.RequestBody);
                IRestResponse responseCreateOrder = client.Execute(request);
```